# Multiple Update Statement in SQL Server MERGE

Tags: sql, sql-server, merge, sql-server-2012, sql-update

SQL Server Version : Microsoft SQL Server 2012 - 11.0.2218.0 (x64)

I got the following exception when I ran this Query.
Exception : **An action of type 'WHEN MATCHED' cannot appear more than once in a 'UPDATE' clause of a MERGE statement.**

I know that the exception was for more than once Update statement in Merge Statement.
would you please suggest me that **how I achieve the following SQL Query logic?**

***Based on One column,

               When Matched and column is not null then update only one different column.

               When Matched and column is null then update the most of the columns.

               When Not Matched then Insert.***

The Complete SQL is

```
MERGE TargetTable AS targetT 
USING   SourceTable AS sourceT ON sourceT.Npi = targetT.Npi
WHEN    MATCHED AND IsNull(targetT.SPI, '') <> '' THEN
        UPDATE SET targetT.Taxonomy = sourceT.Taxonomy --Update Only One Column

WHEN    MATCHED AND IsNull(targetT.SPI,'')= '' THEN --Update Rest of the Columns
        UPDATE SET targetT.state_license_no = sourceT.state_license_no, targetT.NPI = sourceT.NPI, targetT.PrefixName = sourceT.PrefixName,targetT.last_name = sourceT.last_name,targetT.first_name = sourceT.first_name
               ,MiddleName = sourceT.MiddleName,targetT.SuffixName = sourceT.SuffixName, targetT.address_1 = sourceT.address_1,targetT.address_2 = sourceT.address_2,targetT.City = sourceT.City,targetT.State = sourceT.State
               ,zip = sourceT.zip,targetT.phone = sourceT.phone,targetT.Fax = sourceT.Fax,targetT.last_modified_date = sourceT.last_modified_date,targetT.Taxonomy = sourceT.Taxonomy           

WHEN    NOT MATCHED BY TARGET --Insert New Row
        THEN
        INSERT (state_license_no, NPI, prefixname, last_name, first_name, MiddleName, SuffixName, address_1, address_2, City, State, zip, phone, Fax, last_modified_date, Taxonomy, Data_source)
                                    VALUES (sourceT.state_license_no, sourceT.NPI, sourceT.PrefixName, sourceT.last_name, sourceT.first_name, sourceT.MiddleName, sourceT.SuffixName, 
                                    sourceT.address_1, sourceT.address_2, sourceT.City, sourceT.State, sourceT.zip, 
                                    sourceT.phone, sourceT.Fax, sourceT.last_modified_date, sourceT.Taxonomy, sourceT.Data_source);
```

Answer (score 5):

**Please note this did not answer OP question, it was just an elaboration on the MERGE clause.**

As per [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx), "If there are two `WHEN MATCHED` clauses, then one must specify an `UPDATE` action and one must specify a `DELETE` action".

```
WHEN MATCHED THEN <merge_matched>
```

Specifies that all rows of target_table that match the rows returned by <table_source> ON `<merge_search_condition>`, and satisfy any additional search condition, are either updated or deleted according to the <merge_matched> clause.
The `MERGE` statement can have at most two `WHEN MATCHED` clauses.

If two clauses are specified, then the first clause must be accompanied by an `AND <search_condition>` clause. For any given row, the second `WHEN MATCHED` clause is only applied if the first is not. If there are two `WHEN MATCHED` clauses, then one must specify an `UPDATE` action and one must specify a DELETE action.

> If `UPDATE` is specified in the <merge_matched> clause, and more than
> one row of <table_source>matches a row in target_table based on
> <merge_search_condition>, SQL Server returns an error.
>
> ```
> The MERGE statement cannot update the same row more than once, or update and delete the same row.
> ```

Source: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx)

Hope this helps.

Comment: This answer is not helpful. The OP said himself that he is aware of what you posted and is asking for a way to solve the problem, not to repeat why the problem came to be.

Comment: @DRS - totally agree with your comment. I cannot remember why I had replied with this 7 years ago, maybe I was thinking the MSDN article would be a good read for someone who visits this SO page in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Dont consider this as an answer, I did not test the code either..What I tried, is to add a CASE statement for every column.

```
MERGE TargetTable AS targetT 
USING   SourceTable AS sourceT ON sourceT.Npi = targetT.Npi
WHEN    MATCHED THEN
        UPDATE  SET targetT.Taxonomy = CASE WHEN  IsNull(targetT.SPI, '') <> '' THEN sourceT.Taxonomy ELSE targetT.Taxonomy END,
                targetT.state_license_no = CASE WHEN IsNull(targetT.SPI,'')= '' THEN sourceT.state_license_no ELSE targetT.state_license_no END
WHEN    NOT MATCHED BY TARGET --Insert New Row
        THEN
        INSERT (state_license_no, NPI, prefixname, last_name, first_name, MiddleName, SuffixName, address_1, address_2, City, State, zip, phone, Fax, last_modified_date, Taxonomy, Data_source)
                                    VALUES (sourceT.state_license_no, sourceT.NPI, sourceT.PrefixName, sourceT.last_name, sourceT.first_name, sourceT.MiddleName, sourceT.SuffixName, 
                                    sourceT.address_1, sourceT.address_2, sourceT.City, sourceT.State, sourceT.zip, 
                                    sourceT.phone, sourceT.Fax, sourceT.last_modified_date, sourceT.Taxonomy, sourceT.Data_source);
```

I have added update for only two columns. This will be lengthy, but must ideally work.

Comment: nice idea, but It's taking lots of time to execute.

Comment: I would have suggested the same. This articles talks about the idea a little more in detail: https://blog.jooq.org/2020/04/10/the-many-flavours-of-the-arcane-sql-merge-statement/

Answer (score 0):

It's a huge hack, but you could define an "instead of delete" trigger and use that for the alternate update case.

If there are any INSTEAD OF UPDATE or INSTEAD OF DELETE triggers defined on target_table, the update or delete operations are not performed. Instead, the triggers fire and the inserted and deleted tables are populated accordingly

i.e you can do "when matched and..." (update) else (delete). The instead of delete trigger could do an update.

That might work for the case where you're trying to do a "soft delete"