# MERGE: Multiple Statements WHEN NOT MATCHED?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is it possible to write multiple statements when NOT MATCHED?

```
MERGE <target_table> [AS TARGET]
USING <table_source> [AS SOURCE]
ON <search_condition>
WHEN MATCHED THEN
<merge_matched>                      
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
<merge_not_matched>              -- ONE MORE INSERT STATEMENT ON OTHER TABLE
```

> Use of `BEGIN` and `END` not working

Comment: No you can't have BEGIN/END inside merge. But you can use **[INSERT OVER DML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46141570/5070879)** to insert additional record to table that is not part of source/target

Comment: I don't believe `MERGE` will allow you to do multiple operations.

Comment: You could simply write separate statements using exists. That would also have the benefit of not having to deal with the dangers of merge, because there are plenty of them, severity depending on sql version.

Comment: @LukaszSzozda That's a pretty cool way to get around that "limitation" in `MERGE`, but isn't that kinda going around the intent of what a `MERGE` is? If it was intended to do multiple operations, it would let you, at the very least, execute a sproc. But I don't think it lets you do that either.

Comment: @Shawn `INSERT OVER DML` is just extension of `OUTPUT INTO clause`. With simple OUTPUT you have no control over which rows will land into second table. Using `OUTPUT` and wraping entire merge with subquery you could add filters/join to other tab and so on.

Comment: @LukaszSzozda I get what it's doing, and I do think it's pretty cool. I'm just not sure it's what `MERGE` was intended for. There may be a more solid way to accomplish an upsert into multiple tables. Especially considering that a `MERGE` can run into issues with locking and backups. And especially more for anyone still on < SQL2016. It's definitely something for me to look at and play with.

Comment: @Shawn Yes, it was inteded for doing so [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=efeec9642e6680574c6065ec7ad1167e): `A nested INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, or MERGE statement is not allowed in a SELECT statement` **`that is not the immediate source of rows for an INSERT statement.`**