# SQL Server Multi-Target Insert, Does It Exist?

Tags: sql-server

I've recently been advising on refactoring some data processing code, and one part of the system builds up some intermediate data sets in tables and then inserts some summary/aggregate records into a couple separate tables. Since the intermediate data is not actually used, it seems like a waste of resources to materialize it on disk only to use it for some "downstream" processing. For example, Table A gets constructed and then there are INSERT-SELECT statements (all with Table A in their FROM clauses) adding records to Tables B, C, and D. Table A is truncated after B, C, and D are inserted into.

If there were a single table of outputs, there would be no question in my mind - just incorporate the SELECT statement for the intermediate data into the final INSERT-SELECT statement. But since there are three outputs, I am not aware of a way to write a single query which accomplishes this. The closest thing I can think of is incorporating the common logic into each INSERT-SELECT, which would introduce redundant processing instead, which is just another form of waste.

Is it possible to INSERT into multiple tables in one SQL statement?

Notes:

1. I could use a temporary table or table-valued variable to hold the intermediate data, but this still involves storing intermediate data by the programmer. Part of the point of my question is that if this multi-insert were possible then the Query Optimizer / DB Engine would handle that intermediate data storage instead of the programmer, probably doing a better job.
2. I am aware that I should select an alternative based on performance testing rather than theorizing about what might be faster or slower, but this question is not about selecting an alternative. It is asking whether a particular alternative exists or not.

Comment: "I could use a temporary table or table-valued variable to hold the intermediate data" - Careful with the table variables, they can't be indexed like #temp tables can. They are essentially heaps. If you are working/joining against many records then you should use a #temp table instead of a @table variable and consider adding appropriate indexes as needed.

Comment: Technically yes - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46141142/using-multiple-statements-in-when-matched/46141570#46141570 You could INSERT twice in single statement. But I doubt this construct resolve your issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to INSERT into multiple tables in one SQL statement?

Yes but probably not in a way that is very useful to you. You can insert into a table and then use the `OUTPUT` clause to insert from that in to another table but you can't perform any transformations on the stream passed from the first table to the second table except from adding a `WHERE` or discarding rows due to `IGNORE_DUP_KEY`.

A trigger might also technically answer your question but that just hides the secondary statements and moves the processing to be against an additional `INSERTED` pseudo table that is created.

Comment: Thanks, that's very interesting... I haven't come across the OUTPUT clause before. I'm going to investigate to see if it might help. Triggers, on the other hand, are not a direction I want to take - as you have already guessed :)